# Azure Automation. PSMetric to integer

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to create an Azure Automation workbook that queries a resource for some metrics, and does some scaling up/down based in that metric.
I have no idea how I can convert a PSMetricData to integer in order to do comparisons on it. My code at the moment is

```
    $MonitorParameters = @{
    ResourceId = "abcde....." 
    TimeGrain = [TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
    MetricNames = "cpu_percent"
}

$MetricValues = Get-AzMetric @MonitorParameters -DetailedOutput
$Last = $MetricValues.Data[0]

Write-Output $Last
```

And my output is

```
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue
```

I am looking in general for something like:
"If the last 5 mins has a cpu_percentage > 70%", then scale up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Write-Output $Last.Average` instead of `Write-Output $Last`, then you will get the specific value.

And you should note the newest value got from the command `Get-AzMetric` is before the last one hour, e.g. if now is `2:37:00 AM`, then the newest one is `1:38:00 AM`, you could not get the `last 5 mins` value, the `TimeGrain = [TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")` just means get the value every five mins.

**Update:**

It should work, I create a new elastic pool and test it, it is `0`.

My script in the runbook:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

    $MonitorParameters = @{
    ResourceId = "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/joyserver1/elasticPools/joypool" 
    TimeGrain = [TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
    MetricNames = "cpu_percent"
}

$MetricValues = Get-AzMetric @MonitorParameters -DetailedOutput
$Last = $MetricValues.Data[0]

Write-Output $Last
```

[image]

Comment: I dont follow what you mean by the newest value stuff. Also is there a way in Powershell to see the available methods/values of an item? I am still really lost to be honest with this, could you provide some sample code? Thanks a million

Comment: @user98651 1.In short, there is a delay in this command, the newest value you can get is before the last one hour, means you can just get something like `If the last one hour has a cpu_percentage > 70%"` 2. If you want to see the available methods/values of an item, you can test it in powershell in local, you can see them like https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIvof.png

Comment: @user98651 BTW, could you get the specific value with `$Last.Average` now?

Comment: No, it doesnt display anything

Comment: @user98651 What is the resource you are getting metric from? i.e. what is your `ResourceId`?

Comment: It is an SQL elastic pool

Comment: @user98651 What is the version of the `Az.Monitor` module in your automation account? You can check it in the automation account -> `Modules` in the portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222646/discussion-between-user98651-and-joy-wang).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I was creating a powershell workflow, not a native powershell script.
The script from @Joy Wang above now works as described